# Dynamic prepend and remove JQuery/JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to dynamically add and remove items when I press the Append/Clear buttons in this piece of code.

```
                $("#btn1").click(function(){
                    $("ul").prepend("<li>List Item</li>");
                });

                $("#btn2").click(function(){
                     $("ul").remove();
                });

                 $("#btn3").click(function(){
                 $("p").prepend("Prepended items");
                     });
                $("#btn4").click(function(){
                      $("p").remove();
                     });
```

**How do I make it so that when I press `btn1` multiple times it will add a number after it like:**

```
List Item 1
List Item 2
List Item 3
```

**Then if I press `btn2` it will remove them one by one? same goes for `btn4`?**

EDIT:

I used Jai and Oday's answers to suit my needs.

```
var i = 1, p = 1;

        $("#btn1").click(function(){
            $('<li/>',{
                text: "List Item "+i
            }).appendTo('ul');
            i++;
        });

        $("#btn2").click(function(){
            $("ul li:last").fadeOut('fast').remove();
            i--; //added this
        });

        $("#btn3").click(function(){
            $("p").append("<span>Appended items</span>");
        });

        $("#btn4").click(function(){
            $("p").find('span:last').remove();
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with something like this:

```
var i = 1, p = 1;

$("#btn1").click(function(){
   $('<li/>',{
       text: "List Item "+i
   }).appendTo('ul');
   i++;
});

$("#btn2").click(function(){
   $("ul li:last").fadeOut('fast').remove();
});

$("#btn3").click(function(){
   $('<p/>',{
       text: "Prepended items "+p
   }).appendTo('ul');
   p++;
});

$("#btn4").click(function(){
   $("p").fadeOut('fast').remove();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#btn1").click(function(){
    $("ul").append("<li>List Item</li>");
});

$("#btn2").click(function(){
    $("ul").find('li:last').remove();
});

$("#btn3").click(function(){
    $("p").append("<span>Appended items</span>");
});

$("#btn4").click(function(){
    $("p").find('span:last').remove();
});
```

Read more about jQuery functions: append, prepend, remove, empty, find,etc...

Answer (score 0):

```
var btncounter = 0;             

$("#btn1").click(function(){
 btncounter++;
 $("ul").prepend("<li>List Item </li>" + btncounter);
 return btncounter;
});

$("#btn2").click(function(){
 btncounter--;
 $("ul").remove();
 return btncounter;
});
```